# Finding a Monovariant of a certain Map

Tags: combinatorics, invariance

In solving a puzzle related to linear algebra over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, I came across the function $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^n$ given by
$$(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\mapsto(|x_1-x_n|, |x_2-x_1|, |x_3-x_2|, \dots, |x_n-x_{n-1}|)$$
I have solved most of my puzzle, but I am stuck on proving the following.

**Claim:** For any input $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ such that

- Each $x_j$ is non-negative
- There are **at least two distinct positive entries** in our input. So for example, my claim applies to $(7,1,0)$ but not $(1,1,0)$.
  $$\max_i\varphi^n(x)_i<\max_ix_i$$
  In other words, the largest entry of my vector after I apply $\varphi$ consecutively $n$ times will be strictly less than the maximum entry of the input vector.

**Observations & Progress**

- I can prove this claim when $n$ is a power of $2$, but I have checked it for many inputs with $n$ up to 10, and I really want a clean proof of this claim that handles all cases at once.
- Using usual inequality business, we can see that $\max_i\varphi(x)_i\leq\max_ix_i$
- If we have a single maximum entry $x_j$ next to two entries strictly between $0$ and $x_j$ then we can check that the claim holds
- Intuitively, even when we are not in the above case, applying $\varphi$ $n$ times will shift us into the previous case

Any help formalizing my above reasoning to handle the various edge cases or suggesting some sort of invariant would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Earnest That's why I added the condition where the input needs to have two distinct entries. That excludes cases like $(0,1,0)$ but handles cases like $(7,1,0)$ where $\varphi^3(7,1,0)=(1, 5, 4)$.

Comment: The reason I want to prove my claim is to show that repeatedly applying $\varphi$ will eventually take you to a vector like $(0,1,0$ - one whose entries only take on the value 0 or possible one other.